# How to create game achievement in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create game achievements in Java. I have class `Player` and field `int level`. In game each time when player gets exp he can reach new level. How to trigger when player reaches a level 10?(without `if` operator because as I understand it's not correct to check all time on exp gain if player reaches level 10 or not. Becase if I will have more than one achievement?).
My suggestion is to use own event? I'm looking for correct way to perform this task.

```java
package testMyAchievements;

public class AchievementTestMain {
    private static class Player {
        private int level = 1;

        public int getLevel() {
            return level;
        }

        public void setLevel(int level) {
            this.level = level;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Player{" +
                    "level=" + level +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player player = new Player();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            player.setLevel(player.getLevel() + 1);
            /*how to trigger when player reaches a level 10?(without if operator)
             * and say "You reached level 10!"*/
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "without if operator because as I understand it's not correct to check all time" Why do you think that's wrong? I don't see any other easy way to do it, and using an if statement shouldn't impact your performance much. You could have an enum constant for each level, and for the 10th level, you could override some method to update the player's exp, or you could do something else, but everything else I can think of is really complicated

Comment: You could use the `switch` statement. That way you could have different events fired at different levels. But switch is just another form of if basically.

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs Well, switch can be a bit faster, but not by much, and this seems really trivial

Comment: @user maybe he will have thousands of levels in his game and a different achievement for every 10th level :) And yes I know in that case he could probably use modulus instead of switch :P

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs Even if he does have 1000s of levels, the amount of time it takes for `%` and `==` is so small that the user won't notice it. Furthermore, not all the ifs will happen all at once. The player will go one level, then it'll do the comparison, then the player will go another level, and so on. The user won't even realise that that operation happened.

Comment: What about events? Like buttons they have listener ```onClick```. As I understand button not checking all the time (each millisecond) if user is pressing on button or not. They trigger only when clicked. Am I able to make my own event and trigger in situation when level is 10?

Comment: @IljaTarasovs you are mixing apples and oranges, and you are also overthinking your problem. Even if you do implement events with an observer pattern you still need something to trigger that event. And that something is the if/switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I don't think you can achieve what you're looking for without a conditional check. Your requirement is explicitly stating "If you get to level 10 then show an achievement". I think you're worried about the scaling of your achievement system. How about you build a hashmap. Where the key is the level and the value is the list of achievement(s) that are granted for that level?

Here is an example where you can have a hashmap pointing to a a singular achievement but ofcourse you can also use `List<String>` for multiple achievs.

If the level is contained in the hashmap then you show it's corresponding achievement.

Here is an example:

```
int level = 10;
Map<Integer, String> levelToAchievMap= new HashMap<>();
levelToAchievMap.put(10,"Congrats you've reached level 10");


   if(levelToAchievMap.containsKey(level)){
    System.out.println(levelToAchievMap.get(level);

}
```